# The twins look alike—so much so that even their parents sometimes confuse them. (the function of 'that')

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions

> The twins look alike—so much so **that** even their parents sometimes confuse them.

What is 'that' and what is its function?

Comment: "That" belongs to the category (POS) **subordinator** and its function is that of **marker**. Here "that" is introducing the declarative content clause "that even their parents sometimes confuse them" functioning as complement.

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but I think *[**that**]* when "that" is included as a subordinator (conjunction introducing a subordinate clause / complement), it's always *optional*. It certainly is in the examples here (both OP's and mine).

Comment: @FumbleFingers In case of "the fact/idea/belief, etc. **that** S+V, the '**that**' is not optional.

Comment: [The fact I'm a native speaker](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+fact+i%27m+a%22) cuts no ice with you, then! I'd be very surprised if you've actually read any "authoritative source" supporting your claim, so I'm inclined to suspect you're making it simply because you know English well enough to be aware that that *specific* context is less likely to discard "optional that" than most!

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a basic one in my country. The oppositive 'that' is a must and the 'that' is classified as a noun clause due to the fact that the antecedent is a noun: the belief, the fact... .

Comment: "In your country"? Where they speak *English?*

Comment: @BEBYGONES Let's stick to English, shall we. "That" is not a clause at all but a subordinator here introducing a declarative content clause. There is no antecedent; the _that_ clause functions as a complement. "That" is optional in your particular example, though most speakers would, I believe, include it.

Comment: @BillJ I think you are expert in English but as you see [the fact: A] [that S + V: B], A is a noun and B is a noun clause which is oppositive with A(It's the difference in expression; you explain it to me as a 'complement)': B equals to A; A equals to B. This is the grammar that we are taught in schools. This 'that' is not optional at all at least in our country(One of Asian countries).

Comment: @BEBYGONES There is no word "fact" in your original example. The clause "that even their parents sometimes confuse them" is complement of "so", the word that licenses it. As I said before, "that" is strictly speaking optional here. In any case, your original question has been answered. Again, "that" is a **subordinator** and its function is that of **marker**.

Comment: @BillJ Thx. My claim belongs only to " "the fact/idea/belief, etc. that S+V, the 'that' is not optional."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oxford Languages it's a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause expressing a result. (The result of their being 'so alike' is **that** their parents sometimes confuse them.)